# How to run an EXE by using a proxy executable file in Windwos 10?

Tags: windows, bash, cmd, windows-10

I need to use multiple PHP versions on the same computer and want to solve this by following strategy:

- I create a folder like `D:\bin` and add it to the `PATH`.
- I create a bash file for every version (like `php56`, `php70`, `php80`, etc.) and place these files into my `bin` directory.
- The bash file should contain some code to "forward" the command and the parameters to the appropriate `php.exe`, to execute it in the same window, and so to function as a kind of "proxies".

The result should look like this:

```
$ where php56
D:\bin\php56
$ php56 -v
PHP 5.6.40 (cli) (built: Jan  9 2019 15:10:55)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
```

When the proxy files only contain `"C:\Program Files\PHP56NTS\php.exe" -v`, it works. But it doesn't work with passing arguments.

**How to get it working?**

Comment: `bash` is a Linux shell interpreter which is not available by default on Windows. The Windows command processor `cmd.exe` processes by default batch files with file extension `.bat` or `.cmd`. Please open a  [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `cmd /?` and read the output help carefully and completely. Next run `call /?` and read again entire output help. You need a batch file like `D:\bin\php56.cmd` containing the line `@"C:\Program Files\PHP56NTS\php.exe" %*` to pass all arguments passed to the batch file to the PHP executable.

Answer (score 0):

It's still not working in CMD and PowerShell. But here is a working solution at least for GitBash:

**`D:\bin\php56`**

```
"C:\Program Files\PHP56NTS\php.exe" $@
```

```
$ php56 -v
PHP 5.6.40 (cli) (built: Jan  9 2019 15:10:55)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
```